# Ensuring images will look as best as possible on any size using object-fit and a container class

Tags: html, css, image

This is a snippet from my codebase. Here's how I write markup for my images. In order **to make sure that, no matter the specs of the image**, it will look as best as possible most of the time:

```html
<div class="container-class">
    <img class="image-class" alt="" src="img/img1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I am giving a `class` to my image in case I have more images within the container, for easy selection.

```css
.container-class {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    ..
    /* do everything related to the container, floats, etc. */
}

.image-class,
.class img /* If there's no other image */ {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

My goals are:

1. Make sure that no matter what the size of the image that's provided (the images will be dynamic, user input, big, small, weird sized, everything), they will look somewhat good, hence `object-fit: cover;`.
2. Be able to affect the main `class-container` with changes on height / width and the image should adapt to them. Additionally, at times, I might want my images to look in some weird ways, but they'll never go over the `container-class`, no matter what I do. Hence, if my `container-class` has some weird positioning rules, they won't get ruined by by `image-class`' rules. Such, I am free to do whatever with the container.
3. Be able to add `position: absolute` elements on the image, as such the container serves this purpose. Think... a "play" button for your image, which is a youtube-preview. Unfortunately, the `hidden: overflow;` doesn't affect the `position: absolute;`; be careful.
4. Be able to insert more content on the image-class and use `float: left/right;` on the `container-class` to position it on the flow of the page.

Additional things one can do where the same rules apply:

```html
<div class="container-class">
    <a href="http://www.stackexchange.com/"><img class="image-class" alt="" 
    src=""></a>
</div>
```

Things to watch out for:

1. WordPress sometimes, due to plugins / options, gives an **inline styling to the image**, making sure there are no conflicts.

Will update as soon as I discover more.

Comment: Would you mind adding the full CSS so we can see whether you're being efficient in what you do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*they will look somewhat good*" and "*look as best as possible*"?

Comment: @Jamal I'm always worried about being relevant, but I think that I provided my exact code that I use and that it makes sense as to if things are in as best a state as they can be. I understand it's not a "maths" optimization, but an optimization could probably be made for this specific image related task.

Comment: @Mast That is the whole code for images, absolutely nothing else. Every image is coded like that. Sometimes, there's an `<a href="">` behind it. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this, keeping in mind I need my images responsive and to look good. `object-fit` seems to do the job though.

Comment: @insertusernamehere What I meant is that I'm a bit concerned about the mobile's `object-fit` on render time, but it looks amazing, it always cuts images on the right spot, regardless of their size, but it seems to good to be true, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. People will upload huge / small / weird sized / unoptimized images. Just wondering if I can optimize my code even further to handle that.